# Cannot see POST parameters

Tags: ruby, post, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a very simple service that let's me send emails.

Here is the controller -

```
class MailerController < ApplicationController
  def email
    render json: params
  end
end
```

Here is the route to the resource -

```
post '/email', to: 'mailer#email'
```

According to the [Ruby on Rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#parameters)..

> It's called POST data because it can only be sent as part of an HTTP POST request. Rails does not make any distinction between query string parameters and POST parameters, and both are available in the **params** hash in your controller

Yet when i send a post request to `/email` with any parameter, it can't seem to read it...
[image]

The request is here in my `development.log`

```
Started POST "/email" for XXX.XX.X.XX at 2013-09-11 15:38:49 -0400
Processing by MailerController#email as */*
WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
Completed 200 OK in 1ms (Views: 0.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Interestingly enough, if i switch to GET, it works, but when i wanted to use POST, it didn't.. 
Anybody know why this is happening?

Comment: what is that thing you're using to submit the post?

Comment: [Advanced REST Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo?hl=en-US&utm_source=ARC). A wonderful Google Chrome extension

Comment: I wonder if the text/html dropdown has any clues

Comment: i don't believe so.. it's just a content type.. shouldn't have an effect on seeing the params

Comment: could you humor me and send a post of the type application/json ?

Comment: i could.. but i'm not going to be expecting json format, i'm going to be expecting HTML. hence the email message

Comment: Getting a `500` when i switch it to application/json when i pass HTML.

Comment: What do you mean HTML? Like in the body you're typing in things like <a href... ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37200/discussion-between-sircapsalot-and-voronoipotato)

Comment: The screenshot is not necessary. What are the `params` as described in `log/development.log`?

Comment: added it to the question.  I'm not seeing any parameters in the log.. maybe i didn't enable some flag to do that

Comment: Can you post the web server output from the terminal where `rails s` is running?

Comment: the server output is the same as the development.log file. that was my request